# Joint distribution of two conditional distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am trying to understand how a joint distribution is formed when two regular conditional distributions are involved that are conditional with respect to different random variables.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and let there be the three random variables $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$, $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{G})$, $Z:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\mathcal{Z}, \mathcal{H})$. Let us consider the Markov kernels $\mathbb{P}_{Y|X}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{X|Z}$.

1.) My question now is, if
$$\int_{\mathcal{X}}\mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(E) \mathbb{P}_{X|Z=z_0}(dx)=\mathbb{P}_{Y, X|Z=z_0}(E)$$
holds (for some fixed $z_0$)?

On the one hand I would say no because intuitively I would assume that we would need a kernel $\mathbb{P}_{Y|X, Z}$ for that. On the other hand, for some fixed $z_0$, $\mathbb{P}_{X|Z=z_0}$ is simply a measure on $\mathcal{X}$ and not a conditional distribution (i.e., a kernel) anymore, so by that logic the above equation would make sense. Can someone shed light on this?

2.) What is the difference between $\mathbb{P}_{Y, X|Z=z_0}(E)$ and $\mathbb{P}_{Y, X}(E)$ anyway, since both are measures on $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$, so how does the conditioning on a fixed $z_0$ even makes a difference? Can somebody tell me how exactly these two quantities differ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct is:
$$\int_D d\mathbb{P}_{X/Z}\int_E d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X,Z}=\mathbb{P}_{X,Y/Z}(D\times E)$$
Logically, if $D=\mathcal{X}$:
$$\mathbb{P}_{X,Y/Z}(\mathcal{X}\times E)=\mathbb{P}_{Y/Z}(E)$$

Comment: But i have the random variable $Z$ fixed to $z_0$. Doesnt this change the issue

Comment: No. Also if $E$ belongs to $\mathcal{Y}$, as I suppose, $\mathbb{P}_{Y,X/Z}(E)$ makes no sense.

Comment: But what is the difference between $\mathbb{P}_{Y, X|Z=z_0}(E)$ and $\mathbb{P}_{Y, X}(E)$? They re both measures on $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$ and are both with respect to the same random variables ...

Comment: $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y/Z}$ is a function that assigns, to each $z\in\mathcal{Z}$, a probability $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y/Z}( z)$ on $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$ such that:
$$\mathbb{P}_{X,Y,Z}(D\times E\times F)=\int_Fd\mathbb{P}_Z\int_{D\times E}d\mathbb{P}_{X ,Y/Z}$$
Each $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y/Z}(z)=\mathbb{P}_{X,Y/Z=z}$ is, in principle, a different probability over $\mathcal{X} \times\mathcal{Y}$ and different from $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}$, which would be the marginal of $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y,Z}$

Answer (score 0):

*If $Y$ and $Z$ are **conditionally independent** when given $X$*, then

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P_{X,Y\mid Z=z}(x,y\mid z)=\mathsf P_{Y\mid X=x}(y)\,\mathsf P_{X\mid Z=z}(x)\\\mathsf P_{Y\mid Z=z_0}\!(E)=\int_\mathcal X \mathsf P_{Y\mid X=x}(E)\,\mathsf P_{X\mid Z=z_0}\!(\mathrm dx)\end{align}$$

If that was not the case, then:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P_{X,Y\mid Z=z}(x,y\mid z)=\mathsf P_{Y\mid X=x,Z=z}(y)\,\mathsf P_{X\mid Z=z}(x)\\\mathsf P_{Y\mid Z=z_0}\!(E)=\int_\mathcal X \mathsf P_{Y\mid X=x,Z=z_0}\!(E)\,\mathsf P_{X\mid Z=z_0}\!(\mathrm dx)\end{align}$$